# How do I get a dialogue/prompt for var theArray1 and var theArray2 in this photoshop script?

Tags: jsx, photoshop, photoshop-script

Can anyone tell me how I can change the script to have a dialogue/prompt for var theArray1 and var theArray2? It's supposed to 'recognise' a text layer that says username (or anything that I put in the prompt) and changes it to array2 (name or anything i put in the second prompt). It works perfect now but I always have to change the script itself and that takes a lot of unnecessary time. (It's a photoshop script)

```
    // replace text elements in type layers;

// 2013, use it at your own risk;

#target photoshop

if (app.documents.length > 0) {

          for (var n = 0; n < app.documents.length; n++) {

                    app.activeDocument = app.documents[n];

                    app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("replace text", "main()")

                    }

          };

// the opertation;

function main () {

          var myDocument = app.activeDocument;

          var theLayers = collectTextLayers(myDocument, []);

          if (theLayers.length > 0) {

                    var theArray1 = ["username"];

                    var theArray2 = ["name"];

                    for (var a = 0; a < theLayers.length; a++) {

                              for (var b = 0; b < theArray1.length; b++) {

                                        var theString = theLayers[a].textItem.contents;

                                        while (theString.indexOf(theArray1[b]) != -1) {

                                                  theString = theString.replace(theArray1[b], theArray2[b])

                                                  };

                                        theLayers[a].textItem.contents = theString;

                                        }

                              }

                    }

          };

////// function collect all layers //////

function collectTextLayers (theParent, allLayers) {

          if (!allLayers) {var allLayers = new Array};

          else {};

          for (var m = theParent.layers.length - 1; m >= 0;m--) {

                    var theLayer = theParent.layers[m];

// apply the function to layersets;

                    if (theLayer.typename == "ArtLayer") {

                              if (theLayer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT) {allLayers.push(theLayer)};

                              }

                    else {

                              allLayers = (collectTextLayers(theLayer, allLayers))

// this line includes the layer groups;

//                              allLayers.push(theLayer);

                              }

                    };

          return allLayers

          };
```

Comment: The easiest probably would be to use `prompt()` function

Answer (score 2):

For easy UI Photoshop dialog boxes check out [scriptui.joonas.me](https://scriptui.joonas.me/)

After that you'll add two edit boxes, an OK and cancel button

```
// dlg
// ======
var dlg = new Window("dialog"); 
    dlg.text = "dlg"; 
    dlg.preferredSize.width = 200; 
    dlg.preferredSize.height = 150; 
    dlg.orientation = "column"; 
    dlg.alignChildren = ["center","top"]; 
    dlg.spacing = 10; 
    dlg.margins = 16; 

var edittext1 = dlg.add('edittext {properties: {name: "edittext1"}}'); 
    edittext1.text = "Username"; 
    edittext1.preferredSize.width = 180;
    

var edittext2 = dlg.add('edittext {properties: {name: "edittext2"}}'); 
    edittext2.text = "name"; 
    edittext2.preferredSize.width = 180;

// add buttons
var btn_okay = dlg.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name: "btn_okay"}); 
        btn_okay.helpTip = "OK"; 
        btn_okay.text = "OK"; // text sensitive 
        btn_okay.preferredSize.width = 80; 
        btn_okay.preferredSize.height = 25; 
        btn_okay.alignment = ["center","top"]; 
    
    var btn_cancel = dlg.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name: "btn_cancel"}); 
        btn_cancel.helpTip = "Cancel"; 
        btn_cancel.text = "Cancel"; 
        btn_cancel.preferredSize.width = 80; 
        btn_cancel.preferredSize.height = 25; 
        btn_cancel.alignment = ["center","top"]; 


var myReturn = dlg.show();

if (myReturn == 1)
{
    var str1 = edittext1.text;
    var str2 = edittext2.text;
    alert(str1 + "\n" +str2);
}
```

You should be able to integrate the rest with your code.